# Show all users whose status is "user" or "admin" on the list

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue to get users data by their status (Admin/User).

I don't want to show an admin on the list, so help me...

```
 $status= 'user';
```

// I've tried this, but it didn't helped

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = $status";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {


while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 $tem = $row;

 $json = json_encode($tem);

 }

} else {
 echo "Error";
}
 echo $json;

$conn->close();
 }
?>
```

Comment: What exactly problem is ? You don't recive any user records ?

Comment: How did it not help? What results were you getting? We need more details to actually help you.

Comment: i dont receive any user records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to put `$status` in the single quotation marks**

---

if

```
$status = 'user';
```

then:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = '$status'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {


while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {



 $json = json_encode($row);

 }

} else {
 echo "Error";
}
 echo $json;

$conn->close();
 }
?>
```